# How do get seat no when click on it in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have used `for` loop and given its value in the click function so I can get the seat number when the seat is clicked but I only get the last number of for loop on every seat click. can anyone tell me how to get the seat number of each seat?
API Data is

```
    var seats = [
    { name: "Premium", seattotal: "15", cost: "250", id: "1" },
    { name: "Club", seattotal: "30", cost: "150", id: "2" },
    { name: "Diamond", seattotal: "25", cost: "170", id: "3" },
    { name: "Gold", seattotal: "20", cost: "170", id: "4" },
    ];

    function handleClick(seatnumber, seatamount, seatname) {
    alert(seatnumber + " " + count + " " + seatamount + " " + 
    seatname);
    setIsActive((oldArray) => [...oldArray, seatnumber]);
    setAmount((oldamt) => parseFloat(oldamt) + parseFloat(seatamount));
    if (selectseat.includes(seatname) === false) {
      setSelectSeat((oldArray) => [...oldArray, seatname]);
    }
    console.log(isActive + " " + selectseat);
    }

    function seat(totalseat, seatcost, seatname) {
    var seats = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalseat; i++) {
      seats.push(
        i % 5 ? (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={i}
            style={isActive == i ? styles.activeseat : styles.seat}
            onPress={(event) => handleClick(i, seatcost, seatname)}
          >
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>{i}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={i}
            style={
              isActive == i
                ? { ...styles.activeseat, marginRight: 30 }
                : { ...styles.seat, marginRight: 30 }
            }
            onPress={(event) => handleClick(i, seatcost, seatname)}
          >
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>{i}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      );
    }
    totalseat != 0
      ? seats.push(
          <View
            key={i}
            style={{ backgroundColor: "white", height: 20, width: 
    "100%" }}
          ></View>
        )
      : "";
    
    return seats;

    }
    const allseatui = Object.keys(seats).map((key) => {
    const varseat = seat(
      seats[key].seattotal,
      seats[key].cost,
      seats[key].name
    );
    if (seats[key].name != undefined) {
      return (
        <View key={seats[key].id}>
          <Text style={{ margin: 12, fontSize: 14, color: "grey" }}>
            {seats[key].name} Rs {seats[key].cost}
          </Text>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              flexWrap: "wrap",
            }}
          >
            {varseat}
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
    });
```

[image: Ticket Booking Seats]

Comment: *get the last number of for loop* what do you mean by this? I think you also need to share your `handleClick` logic.

Comment: I mean if i click on gold seats which have 20 seats in it i will always get 21 on any seat click on gold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

`i` is declared as `var` and gets mutated during the for-loop when populating the `seats` array. Because it's a conventional for-loop there's only the single `i` variable reference in scope that each `onPress` `handleClick` callback hander is accessing. On the final iteration `i` is incremeneted once more and since it is now strictly greater than `totalseat` the loop is exited. In other words, when `totalseat` equals `"20"` and the exit condition is `i <= 20` there will be 20 iterations and `i` will equal 21 when exiting.

## Solution

Use the `Array.prototype.map` function to map an array of length `totalseat` to the JSX you want to save into the `seats` array. The `.map` callback will receive its own copy of the currently mapped index value.

```
const seats = Array(totalseat).fill().map((_, i) => (
  <TouchableOpacity
    key={i}
    style={
      ...isActive === (i + 1) ? styles.activeSeat : styles.seat,
      ...(i + 1) % 5 ? {} : { marginRight: '30' }
    }
    style={isActive == i ? styles.activeseat : styles.seat}
    onPress={() => handleClick(i + 1, seatcost, seatname)}
  >
    <Text style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>{i + 1}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
));

if (totalseat) { // any non-zero value is truthy
  seats.push(
    <View
      key={totalseat + 1}
      style={{ backgroundColor: "white", height: 20, width: 
"100%" }}
    />
  );
}

return seats;
```